# Taxonomy Parent Term page with Child Terms and their description + teasers (with condition)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm working on a website with several vocabularies. **Two** of them are build like this :

- Parent Term
- - Child term#1
- - Child term#2
- - Child term#3

Only one parent and some children.

I have two Content Type, each uses **one** of these **two** vocabulary. When I create a node I can set only one term (the reference field is a drop-down list).

For the first vocabulary I'd like to show on the Parent Term page all of his Child Terms with their Description and Teasers that are related to them :

- h1 (Parent Term)
- h2 Child Term#1 + Term description + Teasers
- h2 Child Term#2 + Term description + Teasers
- h2 Child Term#3 + Term description + Teasers

For the second vocabulary I'd like to show the same thing one the Parent Term page but with a specific filter. If the Child Term possesses a boolean field set on FALSE then the teasers are not showing and a link to the Child Term page appears :

- h1 (Parent Term)
- h2 Child Term#1 (boolean TRUE) + Term description + Teasers
- h2 Child Term#2 (boolean TRUE) + Term description + Teasers
- h2 Child Term#3 (boolean FALSE) + Term description + link to Child Term#3 page

I know some basics with Views, Page Manager and Panels and I think this is a pretty basic configuration but for some reasons I don't understand how to do it…

Thanks

Comment: Why have the parent term at all if you are only having one value?

Comment: Because I created a complex Field Collection in the two vocalubaries that I'm using only on the Parent Term. That's why I'd like to override the Parent Term and not create a Panel or something.
Sorry I haven't explained why. :)